# Videogame quality GUIs using java

Tags: java, user-interface, desktop-application

Is there a way to design or code "pretty" and stylish yet functional GUIs using any sort of java library?

I mean:
Most developers have, at the very least, seen the sort of high quality GUIs hard-coded videogames such as Gears of Wars or some DVD movies and the like have... complitely customized for the theme of the game or the movie in question with stylish sound and visual effects that go faaar beyond the "rigid" look and feel most commercial software packages.

I once saw an video converter application that didn't even have the blue frame (I don't really like custom themes) all other Windows XP applications have... actually it reminded me of the "masks" we used to set up for the Windows Media Player.

Does anyone know of a way to accomplish that?

Comment: pretty, functional, java and GUI don't go together in the same sentence

Comment: If you're ambitious: google for `opengl java` ;-)

Comment: Christophe has your answer. Green Day is just putting out noise.

Answer (score 0):

While this isn't completely answering your question there are such things that can drastically improve the UI in Java.

TWL - Themable Widget Library http://twl.l33tlabs.org/

There are a few other libraries, but this one is pretty good once you get the hang of it.